# Size/Resize of GHashTable

Tags: c++, c, linux, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my use case: I want to use [glib's GHashTable](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html) and use IP-addresses as keys, and the  olume of data sent/received by this IP-address as the value. For instance I succeeded to implement the whole issue in user-space using some kernel variables in order to look to the volume per IP-address.

Now the question is: Suppose I have a LOT of IP-addresses (i.e. 500,000 up to 1,000,000 uniques) => it is really not clear what is the space allocated and **the first size that was given** to a new hash table created when using (`g_hash_table_new()`/`g_hash_table_new_full()`), and how the whole thing works in the background. It is known that when resizing a hash table it can take a lot of time. So how can we play with these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `g_hash_table_new()` nor `g_hash_table_new_full()` let you specify the size.

The size of a hash table is only available as the number of values stored in it, you don't have access to the actual array size that typically is used in the implementation.

However, the existance of `g_spaced_primes_closest()` kind of hints that glib's hash table uses a prime-sized internal array.

I would say that although a million keys is quite a lot, it's not extraordinary. Try it, and then measure the performance to determine if it's worth digging deeper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I really don't see how you can use 'g_spaced_primes_closest() ' in a real program So I should use this function after declaring a new hash table ?? how do you think it could be used for example in order to store 1000 IP@ as keys?